# Fleet Telematics API fails to find route

Tags: here-api

I use the Fleet Telematics API to calculate tolls when calculating a route (I understand there's no other current API for that as it supercedes TCE).
It's generally slower than the routing API, and the routes are sometimes slightly different for the same points (why ?), but it's mostly OK.
The big problem is that it chokes on some routes, for instance these 3 waypoints:

```
https://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?app_id=xxx&app_code=xxx&waypoint0=geo!46.14571,4.10844;500&waypoint1=geo!44.26294,0.302;500&waypoint2=geo!47.57652571374621,2.6147460937500004;37086&waypoint3=geo!50.77318,4.53766;500&mode=truck;fastest;traffic:disabled
```

The same route on the standard route API is found instantly:

```
https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=xxx&app_code=xxx&waypoint0=geo!46.14571,4.10844;500&waypoint1=geo!44.26294,0.302;500&waypoint2=geo!47.57652571374621,2.6147460937500004;37086&waypoint3=geo!50.77318,4.53766;500&mode=truck;fastest;traffic:disabled
```

**UPDATE**: the problem seems to be that the waypoint radius is not used by the Fleet API (here the radius are 500m, 37086m and 500m). I'd swear that it was working in a previous test but maybe I'm mistaken.

**UPDATE 2**: it's fixed in the current version (current = 2020-12-21)

Comment: Hi, thank you for reporting this!. Our team is looking into it and will get back to you soon.

Answer (score 0):

The transit radius 37086m for waypoint2 is very big value in your fleet.api request and causes to check very much road links in this radius while calculated.
Please reduce the transit radius in the request parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the inquiry but 1) I need big transit radiuses and 2) I've solved the problem for now by going back to the "old" TCE route API and it's working perfectly. So why is it a problem with the new API ?

Comment: Issue has been fixed in our Fleet Telematics API.

Comment: The route is still failing in my test. "Couldn't reach way point 3 due to search timeout"

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport Hello. We have similar problem with Fleet Telematics API. Cost optimization is disabled by omitting vehicle and driver costs, but it's still very slow. For truck, it takes about 12-15 secs to calculate simple route (~1000km). Decreasing mapMatchRadius or mapMatchTolerance has no effect in calculation speed. We're forced to set maximum timeout for longer routes. Is anything we can do to speed up calculations? Maybe disable some options?